# Get-ChildItem with multiple paths - Error if directory is missing

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I am using Get-ChildItem to collect files in multiple paths.

For example

```
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Test1, c:\Test2 -Filter *.xmd -Recurse -File
```

If one of the directories is missing I get errors like these

> Get-ChildItem : Access to the path 'C:\windows\temp" is denied.

First, I do not understand why this directory is searched and second what is the way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that one of those paths does not exists. Get-ChildItem has a few counter-intuitive behaviours. It may be a mix of interpreting the input, legacy functionality and maybe a bug or two.

If you don't use `-Recurse`, you'll get `Cannot find path ...` error as expected.
It will also work properly if you add backslashes to paths:

`Get-ChildItem -Path c:\Test1\, c:\Test2\ -Filter *.xmd -Recurse -File`

or use `-LiteralPath` (`-Path` accepts wildcards):

`Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath c:\Test1, c:\Test2 -Filter *.xmd -Recurse -File`

Add `-ErrorAction Continue` or `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` if you don't want execution to stop at missing path error.

Comment: I never thought of adding backslash at the end makes a difference. But it does the job.
-ErrorAction was my first try, but it takes longer to get the files, cause more directories are scanned.